Polyimide heater doesn't heat up much
I have a new 6.5 cm x 5 cm polyimide heater element that is supposed to have a surface temperature of 41 °C, according to its specs. But it only heats up to ~29 °C (roughly 9 °C above room temperature). I measure this with a sensor I put directly on the element's surface, but I can also confirm that the element barely gets warm when touching it.
The element's voltage is 5V AC/DC, effective output 1W, per spec. I have connected it to a power adapter like the ones used for charging a phone (output 5V, 2000mA). When I connect it via a breadboard and add an LED, I can at least confirm there doesn't seem to be a loose connection, as the LED is constantly bright.
Why doesn't the element reach its surface temperature from the specs? I'd like to use it to heat up a very small space (think the third of a shoebox), but the ~29 °C I get is not enough for that.
The element's spec can be found here.

How much air circulation did you have?

Not more than you usually have indoors.

Assuming the datasheet is correct and you don't have a defective product, then it means you're doing something different from them. (Both assumptions could be wrong but are less likely.)
Do you have a thermometer for ambient temperature? Did you measure the voltage? The current (which should be 200 mA for 5V 1W)? Did you suspend it in the air for the test? And it's not specified, but you need to let it heat up enough that the temperature stabilize.
Did you put the heating element on a metal plate/enclosure? That seems the most likely explanation without more info. Metal, generally being a good heat conductor, would act as a radiator and keep the heating element cool.

Thanks, I measured the temperature with the element being in the air, not attached to anything other than its cables. I waited for the measurement to be stable. Room temperature was around 21°C. Unfortunately, I don't have a device to measure voltage/current.

I see. If you cannot measure its power, then you cannot be sure if your product is defective. If your goal is to heat up a small space, then just putting it in that small space rather than your entire room might be enough to reach the temperature you seek. You might also get away with increasing the voltage a bit to increase the power, if you have another power supply. Otherwise, you'll need to add more heating elements.

Temperature is not a measurement of thermal energy.
A heater device produces certain amount of thermal energy but The temperature depends on environment and physical properties of "anything affected":

Put it in a isolated tiny box and it can make a surface temperature of 500C
Test it in a field in Siberia and it will have a surface temperature of -20

So even the datasheet saying it can produce 41 degrees is also wrong; Unless specified like this:

This device when placed in a normal room without ventilation with normal "Air" and without anything touching it, and without any thermal reflector or isolation or something, can get a temperature of 41 degrees.


The specs basically define it like that - room temperature, not attached to anything.

The heat generated (in Watts) is trivial - it will simply be the product of volts and amps. So if your heater has an applied voltage of 5V and it is drawing  200mA, the heat will be 1W. This is true unconditionally.
Using a 2000mA charger won't increase the heating power - the current will be limited by the element. NOT the charger (provided the heater is in spec).
I'm not sure what the LED has to do with this. The current drawn by the LED has no bearing on the heat load and tells you nothing about the behavior of the heater.
The temperature rise in the specs is only approximate. Also, the specs are based on a free-air measurement at room temperature. Your temperature measurement will be different depending on how and what you have it mounted to.
First thing I would do is measure the voltage and current - don't rely on the spec. If it turns out that the voltage and current are correct, that is what it is; you will need a larger heater or multiple heaters of the same type put in parallel.
If the heat generated was close to what you desire, you can usually overdrive these heaters a bit at the expense of long-term reliability. You normally wouldn't want to do this with the free-air case, but this is acceptable if mounted to metal (think: heatsink). It's maximum temperature and thermal cycling that ultimately fail these heaters, not necessarily the heat output.
